# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: flutter

```
 Starting process 'command   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
  Build command failed.
  Error while executing process     
    Error while executing process C:\Users\ALNATHER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C C:\Users\ALNATHER\AppData\Local\flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\rive_common-0.1.0\android\.cxx\Debug\5e19a734\arm64-v8a rive_text}

ninja: build stopped: .
  ninja: error: mkdir(CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/C_/Users/ALNATHER/AppData/Local/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache): No such file or directory
```